# Filter and control number of items to sum in a for loop list - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, filter

I'm new to Python and stuck. How would I write this?  "Write a for-loop to sum the first 10 non-zero integers"

Comment: Really.  You are stuck on this?  Show what you tried.  Looping over the first 10 integers would be a good start.

Comment: See your textbook. Or google it...!

Comment: How are you stuck? Show us your attempt to code it, and tell us where you are stuck, then we can help you write it.

Answer (score 0):

Take it step-by-step:

```
# example list of 14 elements, 11 elements are non-zero 
mylist = [0, 4, 17, 2, 14, 3, 8, 0, 2, 1, 0, 7, 5, 5] 
# non-zero   1   2  3   4  5  6     7  8     9 10  

# initialize variables
mysum = 0 
count = 1 # counter until we get to 10

for x in mylist:                # for each item in the list
    if x != 0 and count <= 10:  # if both conditions are satisfied
        mysum += x              # add the item to the sum
        count += 1              # increase the counter until we reach 10

print mysum
```

output:

```
63
```

For this example, it excludes the last `5`, because we are only considering the first 10 non-zero elements

Answer (score 0):

If the list is not really much bigger after the 10th non zero integer then I would delete all the zeros, and call sum on the slice of the first 10 numbers:

```
mylist = [0, 4, 17, 2, 14, 3, 8, 0, 2, 1, 0, 7, 5, 5] 

total = sum([ n for n in mylist if n > 0 ][:10])
print(total)
```